# Using https with SSE in node js

Tags: node.js, https, server-sent-events

I'm required to use https (or any other secure protocol) in client server communication which is implemented using node.js with server sent events (SSE).

I'm really new to node.js, and I cannot find an example for mixed usage between sse and https.

I'll be thankful for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have written two blog posts on how to implement SSE in Node.

1. http://bayn.es/real-time-web-applications-with-server-sent-events-pt-1/
2. http://bayn.es/real-time-web-apps-with-server-sent-events-pt-2/

There is nothing special about doing SSE over HTTPS. You just need to set it up properly with certificates.

Comment: How do you set up HTTPS properly with with certificates? Particularly from the perspective of a client?

Comment: @Kebman - it is just HTTP so you set up certificates in the same way you would any other web app.

Comment: Sorry, I asked because I don't know how to set up HTTPS certificates with web apps. For that reason I'd love to hear how you set up such certificates with for a SSE client, so you can receive data from a SSE server running over HTTPS. How do you do that?

Comment: @Kebman

https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-iis-10/

https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm